# troubleshooting Python module loading

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I'm having trouble with making use of Python's namespace packages.  I *think* I'm following the documentation, but Python is having problems loading my modules.
Is there anything in Python 3+ to help troubleshoot issues with locating and loading of modules?  Preferably, I'd like to see a trace of the traversal of  system paths and decisions made along the way.